# Show data from click on a value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html-table

In Front page of my portal I am showing an overview of selected records from database two table where are uid field is common in both.

```
$sql="SELECT e.* ,d.* FROM emitra_basic As e INNER JOIN emitra_device as d  ON d.uid=e.uid where e.block='$user'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  $total_records =$result->num_rows;
  if($row['service']=="active")
    {$totalact++;}
  if($row['m_atm']=="yes")
    {$totalatm++;}
  if($row['bio_m']=="yes")
    {$totalbio++;}......and some more fields and for output 
  echo "<table>"
  echo "<tr><td>". "Total Shop:" .totalatm. "</td>";
  echo "<tr><td>" ."Active Shop:" .$totalact."</td>";
  echo "<tr><td>" ."Shop with bio metric:" .$atal."</td></tr>";
```

and its working fine

It shows like:

```
Total Shop:10
Active Shop:5
Shop with ****:*
```

Now I want this facility when I click on this number, I have detail of all facility means if I click on 5 which is in front of Active shop than it should show all details of these 5 shops from database. How do I create query for this..

Comment: use `where` clause

Comment: @madalinivascu how i run query on click on  thes numbers..please explain

Comment: learn about ajax first and then we will talk

Comment: You can use AJAX or not. It's not mandatory to use ajax for this purpose. If you don't know how AJAX works, you must to create a link in that number 5 (`<a href="another.php">5</a>`), and then in another.php file you must to connect the database, run another query that iterates along all active shops. Easy.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks for your suggestion  but i want to know there are 8 different number of different record means like active shop 5, show with atm facility 3, shop in rural area 2..and other. So how can i manage all these pages..please guide

Comment: With separate files (`file1.php`, `file2.php`, etc) or with a query string (`file.php?type=rural`, `file.php?type=facility`, etc). With last option you save files, but your code needs to identify what type of query you will make and then separate the queries.

Comment: Sorry, but is a too broad question to stackoverflow. You need to try something that we suggest and when you face any errors come back with the specific problem.

Comment: its like when i click on number 5 which is in front of active shops then its show data from database of these 5 active shops.